# Python: reading local HTML files, using findall function to extract text into new HTML file

Tags: python, html, findall

im trying to extract elements from a number of different HTML files using findall and put them into a new HTML file. so far i have

```
news = ['16-10-2017.html', '17-10-2017.html', '18-10-2017.html', '19-10-2017.html', '21-10,2017.html', '22-10-2017.html']
def extracted():
    raw_news = open(news, 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

im creating a function that will be able to read these files, extract specific parts so i can put them into a new html file but im not sure if this code for reading the files is correct. how would i be able to extract elements from these files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the list, open one file (python would ask for a 'string' and say that it got a 'list' instead). Once you are into the loop, you can operate over the file and maybe save the text you want to find and put it in some other data structure. 
Change your working directory to the directory where you have these files and then:

```
def extracted(news):
    for page in news:
        raw_news = open(news[page], 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8')
        # Now you have raw_news from one page and you can operate over it
        # Once the loop is over, the same code would run on the next html file
```